# Entering a Date into a Visualforce page and passing it along to a new Record

Tags: visualforce, date-picker

I am attempting to capture a date input from a VF page and then passing it onto a newly created record. All I want to do is bring up the VF page with a custom button in one object (objectA) and use it as a means of input for creating a record in another object (objectB). I am using what would be a blank Date field from objectA as the means for input for the date. I then just want to capture that input in a controller and pass it into a field of the newly created record (objectB). I don't want to save the value of the input into the objectA.

I am doing this in order to get a proper looking data picker in the VF page.

Here is my current VF page :

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

  <apex:inputfield id="theDateInput" value="{!objbvar.Document_Date__c}" required="false"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

And I am attempting to pass that input into a field for a newly created record with this controller :

public class UploadControllerVendorProdRev {

```
public Date thedateinput {get;set;}
private objectA__c parent {get;set;} 

public objectB__c objbvar{get;set}
public UploadControllerVendorProdRev(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
    this.parent = (ObjectA__c)controller.getRecord();

}       
  private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {

    ObjectB__c  obj = new ObjectB__c();
    obj.Parent __c = parent.Id; 
    obj.Document_Date__c = thedateinput ;

    return Database.insert(obj);        
}
```

As it is now I am not capturing a value. I am only creating the ObjectB record with a blank Document_Date__c field.

I wanted to include the <***NOT USING THIS line just to show what I originally was doing with this before I decided to use an inputfield from ObjectA as a means to have user input, even though I am not saving that input to ObjectA, only trying to pass it onto the new ObjectB record.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you initially provided is going about things the hard way.

My preferred method of taking care of this would be to make `ObjectB__c` into a separate variable in your controller, and then use that in the visualforce binding.

```
public class UploadControllerVendorProdRev {

    // This member variable, thedateinput, won't be needed
    // public Date thedateinput {get;set;}

    private objectA__c parent {get;set;}

    // Declare an ObjectB__c variable to be used later
    public objectB__c objBVar{get;set}

    public UploadControllerVendorProdRev(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        this.parent = (ObjectA__c)controller.getRecord();

        // Here, in your controller's constructor, we need to initialize
        //  objBVar. If it isn't initialized here, you'd probably get a 
        //  NullPointerException when you attempt to reference it in your page

        // We can also set the value of Parent__c in the constructor for ObjectB__c
        objBVar = new ObjectB__c(Parent__c = this.parent.Id);
    }
}
```

Because we're taking care of the initialization in the controller's constructor, you don't need to do it in your `saveCustomAttachment()` method any more. In fact, if you leave that initialization code in your `saveCustomAttachment()` method, you'll likely run into issues (a variable redeclaration error, or perhaps the date being overwritten).

```
private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {

    // This initialization is taken care of in the controller's constructor
    //objBVar = new ObjectB__c();

    // This line was moved into the call to the constructor for ObjectB__c
    //   (as a parameter).
    // This line is no longer needed either
    //objBVar.Parent __c = parent.Id; 

    // We can get rid of this line by changing your Visualforce to use
    //   {!objBVar.Document_Date__c}
    // Trying to use 'thedateinput' would cause any Date stored in 
    //   objBVar.Document_Date__c to be overwritten.
    //objBVar.Document_Date__c = thedateinput ;

    // In the end, this should be the only remaining line in this method
    return Database.insert(obj);    
}
```

To tie this all together, we need to update the binding that you're using in your Visualforce page

```
<apex:inputfield id="someId" value="{!objBVar.Document_Date__c}" required="false"/>
```

The way this works is that Salesforce will first attempt to find an `objBVar` in the standard controller. When it doesn't find such a variable in the standard controller, it looks for the variable in your custom controller (or controller extension).

Since we declare `objBVar` as public, Salesforce has no problem finding it. The input field is then bound to the `Document_Date__c` field of your `objBVar` object, which will have the value from your input field after you press `save` (and not a moment before that!).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can handle it.

1. use the apex variable "thedateinput" in VF

and then copy its value in ObjectB in Apex.

```
obj.Document_Date__c = thedateinput ;
```

2. Create a ObjectB variable and expose it on VF page

Apex:

```
public ObjectB__c objBVar{get;set;}
```

Vf:

```
<apex:inputfield id="someId" value="{!objBVar.Document_Date__c}" required="false"/>
```

and then use it to Insert data in DB

Comment: Ah, you sniped me. Using #2 would be my preferred approach. I do think you would need to initialize `objBVar` in the constructor. OP could also set `Parent__c` in the constructor as well, and use `clone()` if inserting multiple `ObjectB__c` records are required.

Comment: Missing piece of part "1":
<apex:input type="date" id="someId" value="{!thedateinput}" required="false"/>

Comment: @mritzi - Thank you very much for your help. I tried to go with your #1 method. I think it is essentially what I had in my "NOT USING THIS" line above but you put in a value="{thedateinput}". But I am getting a (very vague) "Syntax Error" when trying to use it. I updated my original post to show where I am putting it. I took out the two inputfield lines when applying it so imagine that those are gone.  But even if I can get it to work, won't it show up as an odd looking data picker ? (not a typical data input field ?).

Comment: @mritzi As for your #2 method, I don't know how I would be able to name a field from objectB as the inputfield since the VF page is being called up from objectA...? That's why I was using a Document_Date__c field from ObjectA in the VF - and then attempting to pass it into the Document_Date__c field of objectB. 

I'm really sorry if this was a confusing reply. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DerekF - thank you for your help as well. I'm trying to understand what you're saying. I would I initialize objbVar in the constructor ? I assume you mean the VF page by "constructor" ? I think using an inputfield from objectB would be ideal, but I don't know how to refer to objectB when the VF page is being called up by objectA.

Comment: @Zoom_v by `constructor` I mean inside your controller's constructor `public UploadControllerVendorProdRev(...)`. As for referring to an instance of `objectB__c`, as long as your controller (or controller extension) has a public member variable (or at least a public getter), Salesforce will be able to work it out. Using a custom controller (or controller extension) means that you aren't solely limited to visualforce bindings like `{!ObjectA__c.<fieldname>}`

Comment: @DerekF - thanks again. I have updated my post to show the changes I've made. I am still not getting a value to my Document_Date__c field in my new ObjectB record. I guess I'm wrong in setting it to thedateinput even though that's the ID I gave the line in the VF page ?

Comment: @Zoom_v You're getting there, but you seem to have ignored my advice of initializing `objBVar` in your constructor. You need to take the initialization out of `saveCustomAttachment()`. Also, you need to completely remove `obj.Document_Date__c = thedateinput ;` as the field will be set by the `<apex:inputField>` in your visualforce.

Comment: @DerekF - ok, I guess I don't understand what you mean by initializing objvar. I have named it as a variable. I removed the Document_Date__c line as you said. Since I wasn't sure what you meant by initializing objvar in the constructor I thought you may have meant to essentially change obj to objbvar as the variable used in saveCustomAttachment but that didn't work either.

Comment: The terms 'initialization' and 'constructor' are pretty fundamental to programming. Comments really aren't suitable for hashing out misunderstandings of the  fundamentals, so I'll try to write up my own answer.